# Nginx rewrite, removing image dimensions from filename

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regex

For instance, if a request is made to an image like so...

```
/static/images/00f37ac6291bb6e8_150.jpeg
```

But the 150px thumbnail version hasn't been generated yet and returns a 404, I would like to have it try the full sized base image that will always be available at...

```
/static/images/00f37ac6291bb6e8.jpeg
```

how can I have nginx do this?

This is what I've started but I'm running into issues figuring out the regex. I also don't know if this is the best way to accomplish this.

```
    location /static/ {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        try_files $uri @redirect;
        proxy_pass https://s3.amazonaws.com/<buckets>$request_uri;
    }

    location @redirect {
        rewrite ^(.*)(?=_)(\.*)$ https://s3.amazonaws.com/<buckets>$1;
    }
```

Also this is what I have for regexpal with that regex...I can't figure out how to grab the file extension.

[image: regexpal attemp1]

**Update:**

This is what I ended up doing and it worked well!

```
location /static/images/ {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_pass https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket$request_uri;
    error_page 400 401 402 403 404 @redirect;
}

location @redirect {
    rewrite ^(.*)\/(.*)(_)[0,1](.*)\.(.+)$ https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/images/$2.$5;
}
```

Comment: As I see, you don't have any images on your disk. If that's right `try_files` has nothing to do with it. Am I right?

Comment: You're right!  do you know any way to have nginx check a remote file?

Comment: You should use `error_page` directive

Comment: Please write an answer, don't edit the answer into the question.

Comment: The answer is selected below to give proper credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lO8nX7/1) to test and this regex `^(.*)\/(.*)(_)[0,1](.*)\.(.+)$` matched for string `/static/images/00f37ac6291bb6e8_150.jpeg`.  With this match $1/$2.$5 would be the path to the larger image.